Optimal Strategy for Card Betting Game
I'm mulling over the following question:

You are playing a game with two other people where each player
initially contributes 10 dollars to the pot, creating a total pot of
30. During each turn, two cards are flipped over, and you must place a wager (up to the current pot size, including the option to wager $0).
After placing the wager, a third card is revealed. If the third card
falls between the first two cards (exclusive), you win twice your
wager from the pot; otherwise, you lose your wager. The game continues
until the pot is depleted. What strategy should you adopt? How does
your strategy depend on the pot size, or is it irrelevant due to sunk
costs?

I've been thinking about this question and have been stumped. Some of my thoughts: shouldn't this just be a. binary strategy, where you either bet 0, or bet all of the money in the pot? Where this decision is dependent on whether the spread between the 2 initial cards is wide enough to where its +EV.

I think this question would need improvement before it becomes a well-defined math question. What are the possible cards? Are they drawn uniformly? Are they replaced after each three cards are drawn? What are the strategies of the two other players?

In general, betting either nothing or everything will almost certainly lead to ruin (even though, counterintuitively enough, it is the EV-maximizing strategy). As mentioned in @Greg Martin's comment, the optimal strategy really depends on the other players' strategies, but assuming they bet exactly as you do, Kelly's criterion (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion) maximizes the expected geometric growth rate of your bankroll.

What happens if more than one of you win but there is not enough in the pot to pay all the winners?  Your greedy strategy, which has a lot going for it, is to bet 0 or half the pot, but suppose somebody else does the same.

Someone gave a comment about Kelly Criterion and while I guess technically you would have to think about your bankroll, these types of questions where the amount that you wager is static and very small are typically just thought of as strict EV maximization problems, unless your bankroll is also ridiculously small. But even if your bankroll was small enough, by LLN playing this enough with Kelly bets would get you to a bankroll where you are no longer limited by your bankroll anyway.
If I understand your description of the game correctly, you can only take two times your bet from the pot meaning that in a 30 dollar pot, betting 15 would make it such that you can take the full amount from the pot.
This game has implied odds of 1/3 so if your chances of winning are greater than 1/3 you would bet and so long as the fraction of your bankroll calculated when using Kelly is greater than or equal to 15 dollars you would bet the maximum size.
$$f = p - \frac{1-p}{2}$$
